# Editable canvas in android

Tags: android, android-canvas

I want to make a screen where i can place images, type text and move the images and text around by clicking on them ! What kind of a control can i use to achieve this functionality ?

Comment: Perhaps this explanation will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315495/drag-imageview-or-bitmap-upon-touch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe u should grab a bit deeper and use andEngine for such stuff?

-> http://www.andengine.org/